# How can convert script.log and time.txt into a gif file?

Tags: script, screenshot

I make typescript of terminal session  with script command.

```
   script --timing=time.txt script.log
   #do something
   #then ctrl+d
```

And play it with `scriptreplay`.

```
scriptreplay --timing=time.txt script.log
```

How can convert  `script.log` and `time.txt` into a `gif` file?

Comment: The `GIMP` has a plug for text file -> image (any type, including GIF).

Comment: And a link to `GIMP` if you need one https://www.gimp.org/